# Does CSS media queries allow you to set sizes of elements, for mobile screens, as percentages of sizes already set for the element for web screens?

Tags: html, css

I have a code like this:

```css
.text--heading {
    width: 382px;
    height: 55px;
    font-family: Tomica;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 40px;
    line-height: 55px;
    color: #181E4B;
}
```

I need to make it responsive and decrease lengths, font-sizes etc of most elements.

Does media queries have any facility where i could be able to do something like the following:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
.text--heading {
 font-size: size /* where size is 30% of size already defined previously*/
}
}
```

Comment: No CSS allows that, `@media` or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is to **scale** the element, which  - if I understand your intentions correctly – should have a very similar outcome, at least for the CSS rule you posted above. So the media query would be as follows (where everything would be 50% of the original size):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .text--heading {
    transform: scale(0.5);
  }
}
```

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale()

Answer (score 0):

a combination of CSS var and calc could work, it's CSS3 though and might not work in older browsers.

```
:root {
  --a: 40px;
}
.text--heading {
  width: 382px;
  height: 55px;
  font-family: Tomica;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: var(--a);
  line-height: 55px;
  color: #181E4B;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    .text--heading {
        font-size: calc(var(--a) * .3);
    }
}
```